# Select multiple count(*) in multiple tables with single query

Tags: sql, hive, count, hiveql

I have 3 tables:

1. Basic

| id | name | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Name1 | description2 |
| 3 | Name2 | description3 |

2. LinkA

| id | linkA_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 344 |
| 3 | 3221 |
| 2 | 6642 |
| 3 | 2312 |
| 2 | 323 |

3. LinkB

| id | linkB_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 8287 |
| 3 | 42466 |
| 2 | 616422 |
| 3 | 531 |
| 2 | 2555 |
| 2 | 8592 |
| 3 | 1122 |
| 2 | 33345 |

I want to get results as the table below:

| id | name | description | linkA_count | linkB_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Name1 | description2 | 3 | 2 |
| 3 | Name2 | description3 | 5 | 3 |

my query:

```
SELECT
     a.id
    ,a.name
    ,a.description
    ,COUNT(b.linkA_ID) AS linkA_count
    ,COUNT(c.linkB_ID) AS linkb_count
FROM
    basic a 
    JOIN linkA b on (a.id = b.id)
    JOIN linkb c on (a.id = c.id)
GROUP BY
    a.id
    ,a.name
    ,a.description
```

Result from the query is count of linkA always same as linkB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more traditional approach is to use "derived tables" (subqueries) so that the counts are performed before joins multiply the rows. Using left joins allows for all id's in `basic` to be returned by the query even if there are no related rows in either joined tables.

```
select
      basic.id
    , coalesce(a.LinkACount,0) LinkACount
    , coalesce(b.linkBCount,0) linkBCount
from basic 
left join (
     select id, Count(linkA_ID) LinkACount from LinkA group by id
     ) as a on a.id=basic.id
left join (
     select id, Count(linkB_ID) LinkBCount from LinkB group by id
     ) as b on b.id=basic.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This (using SubQuery)

```
SELECT
 basic.id
,basic.name
,basic.description
,(select Count(linkA_ID) from LinkA  where LinkA.id=basic.id) as LinkACount
,(select Count(linkB_ID) from LinkB  where LinkB.id=basic.id) as LinkBCount FROM basic
```

Method 2 (Try CTE)

```
   with a as(select id,Count(linkA_ID)LinkACount from LinkA group by id)
, b as (select id,Count(linkB_ID)LinkBCount from LinkB group by id)
select basic.id,a.LinkACount,b.linkBCount
from basic 
join a on (a.id=basic.id)
join b on (b.id=basic.id)
```

Comment: I got this error:

Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.calcite.CalciteSubquerySemanticException: Unsupported SubQuery Expression Invalid subquery. Subquery in SELECT could only be top-level expression (state=42000,code=40000)

Comment: try using CTE (as subquery has some limitations in hivesql.),|'ve edited the answer . Also I'm using microsoft sql server so I cannot test the queries,.

Answer (score 0):

If you only select from your table you see why your query cannot work.

```
 SELECT    
    *
 FROM 
    basic a 
    JOIN linkA b on (a.id = b.id)   
    JOIN linkb c on (a.id = c.id)    
 WHERE a.ID = 3
```

=> just use distinct in your count

```
SELECT
     a.id
    ,a.name
    ,a.description
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT(b.linkA_ID)) AS linkA_count
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT(c.linkB_ID)) AS linkb_count
FROM
    basic a 
    JOIN linkA b on (a.id = b.id)
    JOIN linkb c on (a.id = c.id)
GROUP BY
    a.id
    ,a.name
    ,a.description
```